# convert underscore to camelcaps in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to convert an underscore string into a camelcase'd string, in php. How can this be done using `preg_replace`?

For example: `offer_list` to `offerList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done using a /e modifier on your regex, like this:

```
preg_replace("/_([a-zA-Z])/e", 'strtoupper("$1")', "camel_case_word")
```

Comment: Starting from php 5.5.0, the `/e` modifier is deprecated. You should use `preg_replace_callback()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

without preg:

```
 /**
 * Converts underscore string into camel
 * @param   string    $str
 * @return  string 
 */
public static function underToCamel($str){
    return   \lcfirst(str_replace(' ', "", ucwords(strtr($str, '_-', ' '))));
}
```